# Influxdb2 Merge one measurement into another using flux

Tags: flux, influxdb-2

I set up influxdb2 to collect data into a measurement "meas0".
Now I imported historic data using the line protocol, unfortunately I did a mistake with the target measurement and it went into a second series "meas1". The structure and names regarding the fields and tags are the same.

I found a solution on stackoverflox for influxdb1 using fluxQL. I understand that this is not available for fresh influxdb2 installations!?

So can someone show me how to merge "meas1" into "meas0" and get rid of "meas0"?

Comment: Why not import historic data again, into "meas0"? I think you can delete unwanted measurement, see https://community.influxdata.com/t/deleting-measurements/23287.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following solution here:
https://community.influxdata.com/t/how-to-copy-data-between-measurements/22582/4

```
from(bucket: "example-bucket")
    |> range(start: 2021-11-21T00:00:00Z, stop: 2021-11-22T00:00:00Z)
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "meas0")
    |> set(key: "_measurement", value: "meas1")
    |> to(bucket: "example-bucket")
```

There is also a way using map but I cannot find the reference aghain.
Finally, to delete a whole measurement on can use "influx delete --bucket  --start  --stop  --predicate '_measurement="meas0"'